# What is the risk of one-time small exposure to Roundup Weedkiller Spray?

Tags: risks, carcinogens, herbicide

I had an incident that spray some Roundup weedkiller on my foot (but i didn't wash it up in time). The smell is also bad that I may also acidentally inhale some.

I have googled quite some time, and it makes me panic. Some says it is linked to cancers and even worse, the ALS.

Could some one tell me that in this case, could this one-time exposure be Carcinogenic, causing ALS or other health issues?

PS: the label on the spray does not say anything related to the potential health risks.